# enum [tag] [: type] {enum-list} [declarator] in C++ - is this legal?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, enums, enumeration

I am working with a custom enumerated type in C++, but it does not have many values.  I want to try to reduce the size that they take up, and I've heard that `enum` types are [always integers by default](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.19).  I then came across the [MSDN entry on C++ enumerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzy4k6e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), and found the following syntax very interesting:

```
enum [: type] {enum-list};
```

Sure enough, it compiled with what I wanted (VS2008) when I did the following:

```
enum plane : unsigned char { xy, xz, yz };
```

Now, you can see from my enumeration constants that I don't need much in terms of space - an unsigned char type would be perfect for my uses.

However, I have to say, I've never seen this form used *anywhere* else on the internet - most don't even seem aware of it.  I'm trying to make this code cross-platform (and possibly for use on embedded systems), so it left me wondering... Is this proper C++ syntax, or only supported by the MSVC compiler?

**Edit**: It seems that this feature is now part of C++11 and above, and is called [scoped enumerations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum).

Comment: Have you heard of 'premature optimization'?  If you have massive arrays of the enumeration, it might matter.  Otherwise, it probably falls into the premature optimization category.  Check the code size; it might even increase the amount of code needed to manipulate the enumeration values.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, I'm contemplating using either `#define` macros or just `const` variables encapsulated in a namespace to do this... I'm just trying to determine what all of my options are.  I just think that the syntax using this method would be both convenient and intuitive.

Comment: Clarification: Per the C++03 Standard, enumerations are not integral; however, they can be promoted to int, unsigned int, long, or unsigned long.

Also, since enums are not lvalues, they have neither storage duration nor linkage. See this: http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/programming-pointers/4023879/Enumeration-Constants-vs-Constant-Objects

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think that minor update to the question was worth bumping it to the front page after nearly exactly seven years. Strictly speaking, it probably shouldn't even be in the question -- it's an answer, and that's where it belongs (and, in fact, where it is!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As 0A0D's said, the notation you're using is non-Standard in C++03, but has been adopted by C++11 under the term "scoped enums".

If that's not soon enough for you, then you can consider explicitly specifying the bit field width used for the enum fields in the size-critical structures in which they're embedded.  This approach is ugly - I mention if for completeness; if it was a good solution the notation above wouldn't be being adopted for C++11.  One problem is that you rely on an optional compiler warning to detect too-small bit-fields to hold the possible values, and may have to manually review them as the enumeration values change.

For example:

```
enum E
{
    A, B, C
};

struct X
{
    E e1 : 2;
    E e2 : 2;
    E e3 : 2;
    E e4 : 2;
};
```

Note: the enum may occupy more bits than requested - on GCC 4.5.2 with no explicit compiler options, `sizeof(X)` above is still 4....

Answer (score 7):

This is non-standard, but it is expected to be a part of the C++0x standard. For me, when I compile in Visual Studio 2005 with warning level set to maximum I get the following warning:

*warning C4480: nonstandard extension used: specifying underlying type for enum 'Test'*

From the [Wikipedia page for C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Strongly_typed_enumerations):

> In standard C++, enumerations are not type-safe. They are effectively
> integers, even when the enumeration types are distinct. This allows
> the comparison between two enum values of different enumeration types.
> The only safety that C++03 provides is that an integer or a value of
> one enum type does not convert implicitly to another enum type.
> Additionally, the underlying integral type is implementation-defined;
> code that depends on the size of the enumeration is therefore
> non-portable. Lastly, enumeration values are scoped to the enclosing
> scope. Thus, it is not possible for two separate enumerations to have
> matching member names.
>
> Additionally, **C++0x** will allow standard enumerations to provide
> explicit scoping as well as the definition of the underlying type:

```
enum Enum3 : unsigned long {Val1 = 1, Val2};
```

Comment: I think you got this one.  I've been trying to find this in the [C++ Standards](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG21/), and haven't found anything, so I'll assume it is not supported.  Thank you for your answer, +1!

Comment: @Breakthrough: The MSDN page should tell you this, but it doesn't!

Comment: Awesome, seems like this is well documented at this point for C++11 and above ([scoped enums](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)), very glad for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly legal.  Embedding the type in an object to save space however will not be effective without specifically ensuring the alignment.  If you leave default alignment, padding bytes will be added (depending on the architecture) usually to a quad-word boundary.

Comment: Since this was tagged as Visual Studio, it is legal, as in supported (albeit in as a Microsoft specific non-standard extension).  It's clearly referenced in the documentation of Visual Studio 2005 and Visual Studio 2008:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzy4k6e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx  Also, as stated above this will be specifically allowed in the C++0x standard.

Comment: What are we defining as legal? With sufficient warning turned on in the IDE, it warns you it is non-standard.

Comment: Since it is currently a Microsoft specific extension, this is tagged as `Visual-Studio`, and it "works" in that if you use an underlying type specifier then the storage allocated for that enumeration will match what you expect based on the type, I define it as legal in this case.  Moving forward to C++0x (which Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 already has good support for), then all caveats aside, it will just be legal.